# H-flux by any other name

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, kt.k-theory-and-homology, string-theory

There are more than a few papers referring to H-flux and/or H-twist etc.
Is there anywhere a survey relating these variants?

Comment: This has now obtained a short answer on PhysicsOverflow: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/21870/h-flux-by-any-other-name?show=21907#a21907